# Adding user access control to my Flutter application

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, authentication

I am busy coding a hairdresser application for a university project. I have set up User Authentication using firebase, allowing users to sign in/up using email and password. However my application needs to have two roles, hairdressers and customers. The user role needs to determine what widgets a user can see.

Below is my Auth.dart code, followed by my auth_screen.dart code.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import '../models/http_exception.dart';

class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  String? _token;
  DateTime? _expiryDate;
  String? _userId;
  

  bool get isAuth {
    return token != null;
  }

  String? get token {
    if (_expiryDate != null &&
        _expiryDate!.isAfter(DateTime.now()) &&
        _token != null) {
      return _token;
    }
    return null;
  }

 Future<void> _authenticate(
      String email, String password, String urlSegment) async {
    final url =
        Uri.parse('https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/$urlSegment?key=AIzaSyAvod1Xfk4P9zjSRKb4lZzGA9sVIiYOAf4');
     try {
      final response = await http.post(
        url,
        body: json.encode(
          {
            'email': email,
            'password': password,
            'returnSecureToken': true,
          },
        ),
      );
      final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      if (responseData['error'] != null) {
        throw HttpException(responseData['error']['message']);
      }
      _token = responseData['idToken'];
      _userId = responseData['localId'];
      _expiryDate = DateTime.now().add(
        Duration(
          seconds: int.parse(
            responseData['expiresIn'],
          ),
        ),
      );
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;

      
    }
  }

  Future<void> signup(String? email, String? password, var options) async {
    return _authenticate(email!, password!, 'signupNewUser');
  }

  Future<void> login(String? email, String? password) async {
    return _authenticate(email!, password!, 'verifyPassword');
  }

  void logout(){
    _token = null;
    _userId = null;
    _expiryDate = null;
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

//Auth_screen.dart

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:barber/Screens/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../Provider/auth.dart';
import '../models/http_exception.dart';


enum AuthMode { Signup, Login }

class AuthScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/auth';
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    // final transformConfig = Matrix4.rotationZ(-8 * pi / 180);
    // transformConfig.translate(-10.0);
    return Scaffold(
      // resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [
                  Color.fromRGBO(215, 117, 255, 1).withOpacity(0.5),
                  Color.fromARGB(255, 149, 176, 179).withOpacity(0.9),
                ],
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                stops: [0, 1],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              height: deviceSize.height,
              width: deviceSize.width,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    child: Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6.0, horizontal: 80.0),
                      // transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(-8 * pi / 180)
                        // ..translate(-10.0),
                      // ..translate(-10.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 103, 161, 179),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            blurRadius: 8,
                            color: Colors.black26,
                            offset: Offset(0, 2),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        'MyFriseur',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 50,
                          fontFamily: 'Anton',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: deviceSize.width > 600 ? 2 : 1,
                    child: AuthCard(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AuthCard extends StatefulWidget {
  
  const AuthCard({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AuthCardState createState() => _AuthCardState();
}

class _AuthCardState extends State<AuthCard> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();
  var options = [
    'Driver',
    'Customer'
  ];
  var _currentItemSelected = "Student";
  var rool = "Student";

  AuthMode _authMode = AuthMode.Login;
  Map<String, String> _authData = {
    'email': '',
    'password': '',
  };
  var _isLoading = false;
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  void _showErrorDialog(String message) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
            title: Text('An Error Occurred!'),
            content: Text(message),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                child: Text('Okay'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _submit() async {
    if (!_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      // Invalid!
      return;
    }
    _formKey.currentState!.save();
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    try {
      if (_authMode == AuthMode.Login) {
        // Log user in
        await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).login(
          _authData['email'],
          _authData['password'],
        );
      } else {
        // Sign user up
        await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).signup(
          _authData['email'],
          _authData['password'],
          _authData['options'],
        );
      }
    } on HttpException catch (error) {
      var errorMessage = 'Authentication failed';
      if (error.toString().contains('EMAIL_EXISTS')) {
        errorMessage = 'This email address is already in use.';
      } else if (error.toString().contains('INVALID_EMAIL')) {
        errorMessage = 'This is not a valid email address';
      } else if (error.toString().contains('WEAK_PASSWORD')) {
        errorMessage = 'This password is too weak.';
      } else if (error.toString().contains('EMAIL_NOT_FOUND')) {
        errorMessage = 'Could not find a user with that email.';
      } else if (error.toString().contains('INVALID_PASSWORD')) {
        errorMessage = 'Invalid password.';
      }
      _showErrorDialog(errorMessage);
    } catch (error) {
      const errorMessage =
          'Could not authenticate you. Please try again later.';
      _showErrorDialog(errorMessage);
    }

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  void _switchAuthMode() {
    if (_authMode == AuthMode.Login) {
      setState(() {
        _authMode = AuthMode.Signup;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _authMode = AuthMode.Login;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      elevation: 8.0,
      child: Container(
        height: _authMode == AuthMode.Signup ? 320 : 260,
        constraints:
            BoxConstraints(minHeight: _authMode == AuthMode.Signup ? 320 : 260),
        width: deviceSize.width * 0.75,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'E-Mail'),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                      return 'Invalid email!';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _authData['email'] = value!;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration:  InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                  obscureText: true,
                  controller: _passwordController,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 5) {
                      return 'Password is too short!';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _authData['password'] = value!;
                  },
                ),
               
                if (_authMode == AuthMode.Signup)
                  TextFormField(
                    enabled: _authMode == AuthMode.Signup,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Confirm Password'),
                    obscureText: true,
                    validator: _authMode == AuthMode.Signup
                        ? (value) {
                            if (value != _passwordController.text) {
                              return 'Passwords do not match!';
                            }
                          }
                        : null,
                  ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                if (_isLoading)
                  CircularProgressIndicator()
                else
                  ElevatedButton(
                     style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Color.fromARGB(255, 103, 161, 179)),
                  ),
                    child:
                        Text(_authMode == AuthMode.Login ? 'LOGIN' : 'SIGN UP'),
                    onPressed: _submit,
                  ),
                TextButton(
                  child: Text(
                      '${_authMode == AuthMode.Login ? 'SIGNUP' : 'LOGIN'} INSTEAD'),
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Colors.black),
                  onPressed: _switchAuthMode,
                 
                  // padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 4),
                  // materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                  // textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any help creating user roles would help me greatly, thank you!

Comment: You can put a seperate roles in firestore for user. And, by default assign a specific role to all users as customers. And, update using a dashboard to update or add users with hairdressers role.